# Can a SwiftUI Picker return an object ID?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an expense app where a user creates an Account object:

```
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var accountName: String?
    @NSManaged public var expensesAccounts: NSSet?
    @NSManaged public var isCredit: Bool
```

Then once that is created, they create the Expense object, which of course will have a related Account.
In the expense form they select an Account from a picker:

```
                    Picker(selection: $account, label: Text("Account")) {
                        ForEach(accountResults) { (log: Accounts) in
                            Text(log.accountName ?? "No Account").tag(log.accountName)
                        }
                    }
```

accountResults is generated by this FetchRequest:

```
    static var accountSelection: NSFetchRequest<Accounts> {
      let request: NSFetchRequest<Accounts> = Accounts.fetchRequest()
      request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "accountName", ascending: true)]

      return request
    }
```

Expense entities have a relationship with Account entities through originAccounts. This is the function to save the expense.

I would like it to link the expense to an existing account. The expenseLog.originAccounts assignment seems to cause a crash. I think maybe I need to create all attributes of Accounts when I'm saving the Expense object, which is fine, but I don't want to create a NEW account object, I want to use an EXISTING account object. How can I achieve this? Can I somehow get the Account ID from the Picker to use as a predicate in a fetch request when saving the expense? I would rather not use accountName in case a user has multiple accounts with the same name (Accounts can be checking or credit).

```
    private func onSaveTapped() {
        
        let expenseLog: Expenses

        if let editExpense = self.editExpense {
            expenseLog = editExpense
        } else {
            print("creating new UUID")
            expenseLog = Expenses(context: self.context)
            expenseLog.id = UUID()
        }
        print("assigning attributes...")
        if self.expenseType == "One-time"{
            expenseLog.expenseIsPaid = true
        } else{
        expenseLog.expenseIsPaid = false
        }
        expenseLog.expenseName = self.name
        expenseLog.expenseCategory = self.category ?? ""
        expenseLog.expenseCost = Double(self.amount) ?? 0
        if self.expenseType != "Per Paycheck"{
        expenseLog.expenseDate = beginningExpenseDay()
        } else{
            expenseLog.expenseDate = self.userSettings.date
        }
        expenseLog.originAccounts = Accounts(context: self.context)
        expenseLog.originAccounts?.accountName = self.account
        expenseLog.expenseAccount = self.account ?? ""
        if self.expenseType == ""{
            expenseLog.expenseType = "One-time"
        } else{
            expenseLog.expenseType = self.expenseType
        }
        expenseLog.shouldDupe = true

        print(expenseLog)
        print("Sending objectWillChange")
        expenseLog.objectWillChange.send()
```

Comment: But the selected account will be in your `account` property, why not use that?

Comment: It will just be the accountName attribute, which could have a duplicate value. For instance a user could have a "Bank of America" checking and "Bank of America" credit account.

Comment: The tag should be unique, no point in using a name.